# Lavacharts remove float interval using Laravel 5

Tags: charts, laravel-5

I just implemented the Lavacharts in my Laravel 5 app however I can't seem to find a way to solve this small problem.

Here's my current graph:

[image]

As can be seen in the picture, all the data is represented as a float, even though all my chart input data are Integers. Isn't there a way to remove this interval and have the data represented as is?

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[image]

Here's the code extract related to the chart in my Controller:

```
//Instatiate chart
$favoritesChart = LavachartsFacade::DataTable();


$favoritesChart->addNumberColumn('Day of month')
               ->addNumberColumn('Amount');


foreach($favorites as $favorite)
{
      //both $favorite->day and $favorite->favorite_count come as an Integer

      $favoritesChart->addRow(array($favorite->day, $favorite->favorite_count));
}




    $linechart = LavachartsFacade::ColumnChart('favoritesChart')
        ->dataTable($favoritesChart)
        ->title('Number of favorites this month');
```

Is there any way to do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace your

```
 $linechart = LavachartsFacade::ColumnChart('favoritesChart')
        ->dataTable($favoritesChart)
        ->title('Number of favorites this month');
```

with this

```
$linechart = LavachartsFacade::ColumnChart('favoritesChart')
->dataTable($favoritesChart)
->title('Number of favorites this month')
->hAxis(new HorizontalAxis(['gridlines' => ['count' => -1, 'color' => '#CCC']]))
->vAxis(new VerticalAxis(['gridlines' => ['count' => -1, 'color' => '#CCC']]));
```